Подключение к SQL Server: Invalid Connection string attribute
Пытаюсь осуществить подключение к БД MSSQL Server из VBA (MSSQL Server 2019 Express x64, Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC 21H2 х64, работаю на виртуальной машине VMware). Интерпретатор ругается на "objectConnection.Open ", выдавая ошибку: "Run time error' - 2147467259 (80004005)': Invalid Connection string attribute". Data Source менял на IP адрес, не помогло. Не пойму, что не так, помогите разобраться. Спасибо за ответы. Код прикладываю.
P.S. библиотека Microsoft ActiveX Object 2.8 Library подключена, OLE Automation подключена.


Public Function GetTagValue()
    ReDim tempMass(100) As String
    


    Dim connectionString As String
    Dim objectConnection As New ADODB.Connection
    
    connectionString connectionString = "Provider=sqloledb;Data_Source=DESKTOP-U6JF9Q3\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = asutp;Trusted_Connection=yes" 
    objectConnection.connectionString = connectionString 
    objectConnection.Open
    
    
  
    Dim command As New ADODB.command 
    Dim comParam As New ADODB.Parameter 
    
    command.ActiveConnection = objectConnection  
    command.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc 
    command.CommandText = "sp_GetValue" 
        
    Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rst = command.Execute 
        
    objectConnection.Close 
    Set objectConnection = Nothing 


    GetMassCurr = tempMass
End Function


Provider=MSOLEDBSQL;Server=myServerName\theInstanceName;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=yes;

AlexanderSt, благодарю, все работает!
